# Select query slow to update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is probably a simple error, but I'm stumped...

I have a database that has entries inserted using AJAX on a chrome extension, which works great and inserts instantly.

I have a separate PHP file that is being used to output the number of entries in a table. This works, but is takes a long time for the entries to update to the right number when called. I need it to be up to date instantly.

Is there any reason why it's taking so long for the query to output the correct number, when the table itself is updating instantly?

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fyp");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM links")) {

    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    printf($row_cnt);

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simple run:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) AS `nr` FROM links")) {

    $row_cnt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    printf($row_cnt['nr']);

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

It will be the best one. Or if your links are not removed at all you could run:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM links ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")) {

    $row_cnt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    printf($row_cnt['id']);

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: While this is a better solution, it's still taking a long time to update. Though it is updating in phpymadmin.

Could there be something I'm missing? It's taking around 2-3 minutes to update sometimes, should it be instant?

Comment: In this case you should run in your phpmyadmin: show processlist; to check what's happening with your database

Answer (score 0):

Hand off the processing to the database by using an aggregate query and return a scalar result with [`mysqli_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php):

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM links")) {
    $row_cnt = mysqli_result($result, 0);
    printf($row_cnt);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above, whilst both are better solutions, there is still a considerable delay on the output when compared to the database itself. 

It takes sometimes 2-3 minutes for the number to update on refresh.

On localhost it updates immediately, but when brought onto my own site it takes much longer to update.

Comment: So the MySQL database is on a different server from where you are running PHP? If so, I'd suggest investigating the latency between the servers. If not, try using MySQL performance tools to determine the cause of the delay. Failing that it could be simply a lack of available resources on the server.

Comment: I believe it is lack of resources available on the server, as the database is on the same server as the PHP. I shall try a different approach, thanks.